# DirectX 9 specular component of vert and alpha channel

Tags: c++, directx

Suppose I locked DX9 mesh vertex buffer, and took one vertex:

```
    int nr = 0.1 * 255;
    int ng = 0.4 * 255;
    int nb = 0.6 * 255;

    ((D3DVERTEX*)pSrc)[i].specular = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0xFF, nr, ng, nb);
```

I trying change specular component of the vertex. And colors nr, ng, nb is applied. But when I trying change alpha component from 0xFF to 0x00 - nothing happens. Why alpha component not influenting? How I can switch on alpha component in specular color of vert?

Comment: May I ask why you're using directX9? It's quite outdated this days and surely it would be easier to use a newer one which may have more tutorials/people who understand it.